# How to display at most 250 character and the rest of the string as '.... {X} more words'

Tags: asp.net, string, c#-4.0

Here i want to count total characters while binding database and display only 250 characters and remaining like '....' 631 more words

by using c# code behind 
thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: You can try to use `string.Substring(0, 250)` to get the 1st 250 characters, then you can add a "..." to it.

Comment: SELECT LEFT(ColumnName,250) from TableName will display only 250 character in query

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using an new extension method.  The logic below will guarantee that you do not cut a word up in the middle, and that the "more words" part won't be included unless the string was actually cut off:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCutOffString(this string text, int maxLength)
    {
        var totalChars = 0;
        var words = text.Split(' ');
        var wordsToInclude = words.Where(word => (totalChars += word.Count()) < maxLength).ToList();
        var initialText = string.Join(" ", wordsToInclude);
        var numWordsExcluded = words.Count() - wordsToInclude.Count();
        var format = numWordsExcluded == 0 
                       ? "{0}" : "{0}... {1} more word" 
                       + (numWordsExcluded > 1 ? "s" : "");
        return string.Format(format, initialText, numWordsExcluded);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
"very long string with many words".ToCutOffString(25);
```

Comment: Seems Good. But its not returning "More words" correctly.                    var numWordsExcluded = words.Count() - initialText.Split(' ').Length;

Comment: @DebajitMukherjee I have fixed the issue by including a `ToList` on the initialization of the `wordsToInclude` variable.  The problem was that that `IEnumerable` was using a closure over the local `totalChars` variable, which was changed after the first evaluation of the `wordsToInclude` variable.  Calling `ToList` evaluate the `IEnumerable` and keeps in memory so that its evaluation won't change.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it in your query

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName,250) + '...' + (DATALENGTH(ColumnName)-250) + ' more words' from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

To return correct "More words" you need to use this

```
 var numWordsExcluded = words.Count() - initialText.Split(' ').Length;
```

Comment: could you please share your email here @ Debajit Mukherjee please